# Counting distinct values via fuzzy matching in an unpivoted table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following unpivoted table:

```
ID    TYPE       VALUE
a     Address    123 Field Ave
b     Name       John Smith
a     Address    123 Field Avenue         
a     Name       Jeff Grant 
b     Name       John S. Smith
b     Name       JEFF GRANT
```

The objective is: If two records have the same ID and TYPE, then it would compare all the VALUES and count the number of distinct values.

Currently, this gives:

```
ID   TYPE      Number_of_Records
a    Name      2
a    Address   2
b    Name      2
```

The desired output is to have the following through fuzzy matching (e.g. John S. Smith and John Smith would count as 1 record).

```
ID   TYPE      Number_of_Records
a    Name      1
a    Address   1
b    Name      2
```

Please note the original table has hundred-thousands of records and the fuzzy matching cannot be done manually, and that there are no uniqueIDs among the records. In fact, it would be great to somehow use the Jaro-Winkler method where if the similarity is greater than a specified number (e.g. 0.8), then it would count as one record.

Comment: How do you determine the fuzzy part? That's the problem. There's potentially hundreds of *rules* you could enforce, or ignore. Replacing special characters with `''` is simple for the `John S. Smith`, and `Ave` for `Avenue` but you'd have to code fore every single case. `Count(Distinct [Value])` or if you are using case sensitive collation `Count(Distinct lower([Value]))`  would work for exact matches. You may need to look into [**CONTAINS**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/contains-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: Yeah, that's why it would be optimal to use something like the Jaro-Winkler method...